# Target transformation from fish eye camera to real flat image without calibration

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

I have camera with fish eye mounted in box, it sees target from behind. I get circles but they are deformated with fish eye. There is no chance of calibrating with chessboard as opencv has function. I have real size of circles in target and need to get transformation function or something, that when laser shoots to some point in target to transform it for real place of impact for presenting it on flat target.

I've already done some preprocessing, got estimated circles with canny and finding contours. Note that center of camera will not always be perfectly on center of target. I have each circles size on real target and that's all I have. Already tried perspective warp and some other functions in OpenCV but with no good results.

Real circle sizes from middle in mm:
5
12
28
44
60
76
92
108
124
140
156

input image:
[image]

found contours: 
[image]

Expected result is transformation matrix or some kind of function that will get me real coordinates based on point on input target from camera.

Comment: Well, I didn't solve this, so I used fisheye calibration built in OpenCV from chessmatrix images. But if someone give good approach I'd like to know that.